# Make child element wider than parent element in one direction

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting a centered, two-column layout and I'd like to have horizontal rules in the right column extend all of the way to the right edge of the browser viewport. This will require those elements to be wider than the parent column they are contained in, but only on the right hand side.

Here's an example image:

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [sans-concept.com](http://sans-concept.com/temp/layout.jpg))</sub>

And here is a quick mockup at JSFiddle, with HRs that are in place but not extending outside of the container yet:

http://jsfiddle.net/ericcarl/3fQKe/

This gets me close:

```css
hr {
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
}
```

But it extends the HR across the entire page and not just the right hand side. Any ideas on this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that gets as close as you can to the effect you want? Be sure to uncheck the "Normalized CSS" box.

Comment: p.s. how did you make your beautiful mock-up?

Comment: Sure, jsfiddle mockup here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ericcarl/3fQKe/

And paislee, the mockup image was just put together using Photoshop. Glad you dig it!

Comment: Can this website utilize CSS3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you make sure that your whole creation is inside of a screen-sized div with property 
overflow:hidden;
then you could make them infinitely long, and the end user shouldn't be able to tell.

Something like
width:500%; 
should do the trick.

http://jsfiddle.net/hx2YF/

Here's a fiddle.  Drag the result window so it's large enough to see the result.

Comment: This is a clever solution and seems to work pretty well. Thanks rfinz!

Comment: You're welcome! Been laying out a lot of things in CSS the last few days. :P

Comment: Actually a better solution that I would've come up with - this deals with the problem very appropriately in older browsers too. Great job! :)

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty here is that the distance from the container's left edge and the right end of the viewport must be known for pixel perfection. See @animuson's (pessimistic) answer for corroboration. I opt for jQuery in these kinds of situations:

```css
#container {        
    position: relative; /*hr will start at the left edge of the container*/
}
#container hr {
    left: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Then patch in [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and run this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // calculate the width        account for container padding vv
    var w = $(window).width() - $('#container').offset().left - 10;
    // apply the width
    $('#container hr').width(w);
});​
```

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/vaqbQ/)

---

**UPDATE**

- [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/paislee/vaqbQ/1/) - accommodates window re-size.

Comment: Thanks a bunch paislee, this might be my preferred solution. Since this is calculated when the page loads, if I resize the browser the size doesn't update, but I assume there's a solution to that as well.

Comment: @EricCarl yep. just extract the logic into a function FOO that you wire up like `$(document)ready(FOO);` and `$(window).resize(FOO);` Will post demo..

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for an absolutely positioned element to know both the left side of its immediate parent and the right side of the root element at the same time. Also, by making your horizontal rules absolutely positioned, you'd be removing them from the flow of the document, so your text will collapse up underneath them. You'd then have to add extra padding, etc to push it back down.

Since you're not using pre-defined width positions where everything with **definitively** be on the page, there's not really any way to get this perfect. You can make the `<hr>` just bigger than its parent with a percentage (for example) but it won't extend all the way to the edge of the viewport exactly for every screen size (some will push past creating a horizontal scrollbar).

Answer (score 0):

If the right column is transparant you could use a background image on the body tag, but that will only work if the rules have a fixed position in your document (like in a header).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately they don't have a fixed position so that won't work for me. The rules will be interspersed through the content and need to change position as the content changes.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a starter for ten, which you can [view on JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pMxtF/).

I used the following sample HTML and CSS

HTML

```
<div id="example">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Example text followed by a horizontal rule 
        example text followed by a horizontal rule
        example text followed by a horizontal rule.</p>
    <hr>
    <p>Example text followed by a horizontal rule 
        example text followed by a horizontal rule
        example text followed by a horizontal rule.</p>
    <hr>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#example {
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #FCFCFC;    
}

#example hr {
    width: 150%;    
}
```

**Fixed Pixed Width**

You can get the same end result with a fixed pixel width, but it is a bit more fiddly.

I have forked your example to [demonstrate this solution on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sohnee/XYJ32/).

Based on the HTML you supplied, the CSS is:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;   
}

.wrapper { /* Center the layout */
    width:800px;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.leftCol { /* Left column */
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    background-color:#ccc;
    margin:0;
}
.rightCol { /* Right column */
    width:600px;
    float:right;
    background-color:#dadada;
    margin:0;
}
hr {
    /* Make the HR extend to the
    right edge of the viewport,
    outside of .rightCol*/
    width: 200%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: auto;   
    }
    hr {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Please note that the final part of this solution uses a media query to reset the values when the viewport is resized below 800px as at this point you do want to allow the horizontal scrollbar. Media queries do not work in some older browsers, so you'll need to test it in the browsers you want to support. The worst case scenario is that your users lose the ability to scroll horizontally in older browsers.

Comment: Thanks Sohnee. My layout has fixed pixel widths for all of the columns though (check my jsfiddle mockup here: http://jsfiddle.net/ericcarl/3fQKe/) so I'm not sure if a percentage approach will work. I tried working with 100+ percentages in my fiddle and while they do extend outside the container they then create a horizontal scrollbar.

Comment: @EricCarl I have added a "second half" to my answer that applies specifically to your example - I hope it helps.